# what is the coupons data structure of an order in woocommerce?

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I am trying to extract coupon data from an order. I know how get the order: $order->get_used_coupons but I don't know the data structure. Some one can help me?

Comment: This is a long shot, but have you googled the documentation? Or better - var_dump the response and look at the data structure directly

Comment: Yes I did but no much info about that, anyway I'm trying to get it using a plug in.

Comment: As EatPeanutButter suggests, you can `var_dump()` the response or `error_log(json_encode($response))` into the `WP_DEBUG_LOG`

Answer (score 0):

Finally I found out the solution. There is not exactly a structure, just a string with the coupon name but you can manage coupons with properties. Here the class definition and properties: https://docs.woothemes.com/wc-apidocs/class-WC_Coupon.html It can be used this way: $coupon->property. For instance ... if you want take the expiration date then would be $coupon->expiry_date.